# Sort by Multiple Columns in PyQt Model

Tags: python, sql, sorting, pyqt, qsqltablemodel

I want to use the `PyQt` equivalent of the following `SQL` statement in my model/view-based `PyQt` application:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY foo, bar
```

How do I sort by multiple columns in a `QSqlTableModel`, especially since `setSort()` accepts a single `column` argument?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's an alternative to `setSort()`, called `setFilter()`.
From the PyQt docs:

> QSqlTableModel.setFilter (self, QString filter)
>
> Sets the current filter to filter.
>
> The filter is a SQL WHERE clause without the keyword WHERE (for
>   example, name='Josephine').

Ergo, this solves the problem:

```
fooModel.setFilter("never_zero != 0 ORDER BY foo, bar")
```

where the `never_zero` field is (surprise, surprise) never zero.

Comment: This is more like cheating and might be misleading. You usually don't expect sorting query in filters. `QSqlTableModel` is rather limited when you need complex queries. `QSqlQueryModel` should be the option. If you need write access, you can subclass it to provide appropriate methods. Or if your dataset is not that big, you might consider putting a custom `QSortFilterProxyModel` in between. It needs to be custom, since original `QSortFilterProxyModel` also expects single column for sorting, but it is rather easy to subclass and provide your own sorting implementation.