# Escape user-supplied strings for QSqlTableModel.setFilter

Tags: python, pyqt5, sql-injection, qsqltablemodel

I want to use a `QSqlTableModel` to give me filtered data, with the filters derived from user input. I know that I can pass a `WHERE` clause without the `WHERE` to `QSqlTableModel.setFilter`. That method, however, looks very permissive (eg. it can [run on into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557698/1274613) [`ORDER BY` clauses](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33106-qsqltablemodel-quot-order-by-quot-clause-in-setfilter)).

How do I escape arbitrary strings or regexes supplied by the user, which to be passed to `QSqlTableModel.setFilter` as filters? If I have [Little Bobby Tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) in my database, I want the user to be able to find him, what should I use for `escape`?

```
QSqlTableModel.setFilter("name REGEXP {:}".format(
    escape(
        "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --"))
```